# Pulling messages from server and rendering on clientside

Tags: javascript, php

```
$scope.receivefb = function receivefb(){
    var url ="js/db.php";
    $http.post(url).success(
      function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.msg!=""){
  document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<div class="row message-body"><div class="col-sm-12 message-main-receiver"><div class="receiver"><div class="message-text" name="messaggio" id='+data.id+'>'+data.msg+'</div><span class="message-time pull-right">Sun</span></div></div></div>';

            }
            $timeout($scope.receivefb, 2000);

      })


}
```

i am using this javascript function to call every 2 seconds a php script that gets the last message from the db and then i print it. I don't to use this timeout thing, instead, i want to use a sort of script that is always listening and triggers my javascript every time a new message is detected.
The concept is pretty simple, but i don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Answer (score 1):

In fact You cannot detect if there is a new message if You don't do request to server or server does inform client-side via some web socket or "web-socket alike" technology.

There are at least 2 solutions:

1) Use socket.io develop serverside web-socket app, bind to some message event and put new message to `$scope.messages` array, delegate rendering logic to angular. Pros is that it works event based and it has "real-timeness", cons is You've to learn nodejs and have nodejs server (simple cheap lamp server hostings may not have nodejs support).

2) Or just simply keep polling for messages every 2 sec separately from rendering logic and put new message to `$scope.messages`, delegate rendering logic to angular (watch [ng-repeat tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=angular%20ng-repeat%20array%20of%20messages)):

JS part (inside of `MessagesController`):

```
$scope.messages = [];
function receivefb(scope) {
  var url ="js/db.php";
  $http
    .post(url)
    .success(function(data) {
      if(response.msg != '') {
        scope.messages.push(data);
      }
    })
    .finally(function() {
      (function(method, scope) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          method(scope);
        }, 2000)
      )(receivefb, scope);
    });
}
receivefb($scope);
```

HTML part:

```
<div ng-controller="MessagesController">

  <div ng-repeat="message in messages" class="row message-body">
    <div class="col-sm-12 message-main-receiver">
      <div class="receiver">
        <div class="message-text" name="messaggio" id="{{message.id}}">
          {{message.msg}}
        </div>
        <span class="message-time pull-right">Sun</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As @Siguza pointed out briefly in the comment section of the question, u can use websockets. Polling is not really a good solution. "WebSockets is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.”

Comment: @stevenvanc seems like You did not read my answer carefully, see (1). In my answer I gave 2 solutions: 1st one for situations if developer has full control on server and he can install nodejs, 2nd one for situations when customer has cheap 5$/mo hosting which has whm, cpanel, php, mysql and etc.

Comment: "In fact You cannot detect if there is a new message if You don't do request to server." - it's your text on the top and point 2. Info under 1. I agree with.